# Digispark micro + SSD1306 - compilation error

Tags: arduino

I'm the owner the Digispark micro and gm009605v4 OLED display. But I'm not able compile this project

```
#include <Adafruit_GFX.h>
#include <Adafruit_SSD1306.h>

#define OLED_Address 0x3C
Adafruit_SSD1306 oled(1);

void setup() {
  oled.begin(SSD1306_SWITCHCAPVCC, OLED_Address);
}

void loop() {
  oled.clearDisplay();
  oled.setTextColor(WHITE);
  oled.setCursor(0,0);
  oled.println("Hello!");
  oled.display();
}
```

The error message is

```
    Arduino: 1.8.12 (Windows 10), Board: "Digispark (Default - 16.5mhz)"

    In file included from C:\Users\lin\Documents\Arduino\sketch_jun11a\sketch_jun11a.ino:1:0:

    C:\Users\lin\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit-GFX-Library-master/Adafruit_GFX.h:113:28: error: '__FlashStringHelper' does not name a type

       void getTextBounds(const __FlashStringHelper *s, int16_t x, int16_t y,

                                ^

    C:\Users\lin\Documents\Arduino\libraries\Adafruit-GFX-Library-master/Adafruit_GFX.h:113:49: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of 's' with no type [-fpermissive]

       void getTextBounds(const __FlashStringHelper *s, int16_t x, int16_t y,

                                                     ^

    In file included from c:\users\lin\appdata\local\arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avr-gcc\4.8.1-arduino5\avr\include\avr\io.h:99:0,

                     from c:\users\lin\appdata\local\arduino15\packages\arduino\tools\avr-gcc\4.8.1-arduino5\avr\include\avr\interrupt.h:38,

                     from C:\Users\lin\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\digistump\hardware\avr\1.6.7\cores\tiny/WProgram.h:8,

                     from C:\Users\lin\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\digistump\hardware\avr\1.6.7\cores\tiny/Arduino.h:4,

                     from sketch\sketch_jun11a.ino.cpp:1:

And more....
```

Can you help me, please? I have installed latest Adafruit SSD1306. Or is there another library for work with this display? Noone example I found and tried worked for me

Answer (score 0):

Adafruit has stated the following:

It will compile if you set the processor to digispark pro.

Why it is that way is known to them.

**EDIT: The problem was solved** - New problem TwoWire does not name a type. Solution for that:

The adafruit library is directly referencing the TwoWire class which is normally defined in wire.h.  For the Digistump boards, they have a similar class but it is called WUI_TWI, not TwoWire.

Probably the easiest way to fix this would be to modify the wire.h file that came from Digistump. add this near the end of the file wire.h

```
extern USI_TWI Wire;
#define TwoWire USI_TWI    // add this line
#endif
```

The wire.h file (in windows) will be located in

```
 C:\Users\YOUR_USERNAME\AppData\Local\Arduino15\packages\digistump\hardware\avr\1.6.7\libraries\Wire
```

make sure it is this one for digistump with the USI_TWI class, not the standard arduino one with the TwoWire class

Comment: No, when I set proccessot to Digispark Pro the result is same. Again error ocured

`C:\Users\lin\Documents\Arduino\libraries\arduino_258556/Adafruit_SSD1306.h:129:42: error: 'TwoWire' has not been declared
   Adafruit_SSD1306(uint8_t w, uint8_t h, TwoWire *twi = &Wire,
C:\Users\lin\Documents\Arduino\libraries\arduino_258556/Adafruit_SSD1306.h:171:3: error: 'TwoWire' does not name a type
   TwoWire *wire;`

Comment: The first error is solved, Error != Error - read the details in the message. Answer for the next problem is in my edit. And next time please open a new question.